# How to find out the username who executed the retention package ? ( RDS SQL SERVER )

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds

I am using AWS RDS Sql server. could you help me to find out the username who executed below package in the backend ?

1. this command shows current retention setting :

   exec rdsadmin..rds_show_configuration;
2. iam setting the retention  to 1 day ( 1440 min )

   EXEC rdsadmin..rds_set_configuration 'tracefile retention',1440;

After #2, i should be able to find who has executed #2 in the database.

Thanks